# Can anyone tell me why R is giving me two different answers for this code?

Tags: r

I have this code that takes a response from a specific cell in my excel sheet:

```
if (data$response.keys[215] == 's'){
    selection <- 0
}else{
    selection <- 1
}
```

It gives the correct information. However, when I was messing around with something and wrote it using the data$, it tells me that the information is in 163 and not 215.

```
which(data$response.keys == 's')
output: 163L
```

I also found that if I plug 163 into the top code instead of 215 it still gives me the correct answer. I was just wondering why this happens even though it doesn't appear to actually be causing any problems.

Comment: The `163` is the index for the TRUE values, where as `215` is the actual position index of the original vector

Comment: @akrun, can you elaborate? Because as I know, vector of TRUE/FALSE and vector of original values should have the same lenght and thus for which we should observe 215 as well. This gives the same output: `c("d", NA, "s", NA)[[3]] == 's'`; `which(c("d", NA, "s", NA) == 's')`

Comment: OP didn't provide a reproducible example.  It is not clear what the object is.  It could have `NULL` values as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Help us help you by posting a data example we can use.